# Prevent VBA from converts txt to American standards

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a script that reads the content of the line of a txt file than places to the extension of the strings in the excel sheet.

My problems is that in some lines it somehow copies the content as American date standard and changes the order os mm and dd to the excel cell. For the other lines, everything goes smoothly and follow the pattern I want.

Here are the print, as the full data is confidential,

[image]

[image]

my code:

```
Sub import_report_txt()
    Dim lineContent As String

    Open "/Users/aniellima/Desktop/Macros/file.txt" For Input As #1
    
    
    
    Range("A5:G10000") = Empty
    Range("A5").Select
  
    
    Do While EOF(1) = False
    

        Line Input #1, lineContent
       
    
            
        If IsNumeric(Mid(lineContent, 10, 12)) = True Then
        
            Cells(CtrEmpreendimento.Row, 1) = Mid(lineContent, 10, 12)
            Cells(NmeEmpreendimento.Row, 2) = Mid(lineContent, 23, 35)
            
        End If
        
        
        
        If IsNumeric(Mid(lineContent, 1, 12)) = True Then
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1) = Mid(lineContent, 1, 12)
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2) = Mid(lineContent, 14, 36)
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3) = Mid(lineContent, 51, 4)
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4) = CDate(Mid(lineContent, 56, 10))
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5) = Mid(lineContent, 67, 10)
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6) = CDbl(Mid(lineContent, 78, 11))
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7) = CDbl(Mid(lineContent, 90, 14))
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column).Select
            
       
        End If
        

        
    Loop
    
    
    Close 1
    
   

End Sub
```

Can anyone see what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I can't use CDATE for the column where I get the issue, as 00/00/0000 aren't recognized as dates.

Comment: `I can't use CDATE for the column where I get the issue` - so format that column as text before setting that value to it?

Comment: I cannot count how many times this issue has come up in this forum. The answer is always the same. Do not **Open** the text file. Use one of the **Import** methods and inform Excel of the date order of the column at the time of importation. You can do this using the `QueryTables` object; Power Query; `Workbooks.OpenText`; a dialog box with the proper argument, etc